# Understanding One of Fermat's little theorem's proof

Tags: number-theory

**Fermat's Little theorem :**
Let $p$ be a prime which does not divide the integer $a$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\mod p)$.

**Leibniz's proof**

- suppose that $ra$ and $sa$ are the same modulo $p$, then $r \equiv s (\mod p)$. {So the first p-1 multiples of a are distinct and non zero}.
- Therefore $a, 2a, 3a, ... (p-2)a, (p-1)a$ must be congruent to $1, 2, 3, ... p-2, p-3$ in some order
- Multiply all these congruences we get $a^{p-1}(p-1)! \equiv (p-1)! (\mod p)$
- Divide by $(p-1)!$ on both sides we get $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\mod p)$

**My issues with a full understanding of the proof**

The text I've put in between brackets {} are the parts of the proof I haven't understood

- first brackets: {So the first p-1 multiples of a are distinct and non zero}. Isn't that implied in the statement of the proof? Why is that part of the proof necessary?

**What is the proof that the first $p-1$ multiples of $a$ will necessarily be congruent to 1, 2 ... p-1 in some order?**

Comment: I think they are just emphasizing that point for people who aren't comfortable with these types of arguments

Answer (score 1):

Because if $ak \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, for some $1 \leq k \leq p-1$, then $p \mid ak$. But, by Euclid's Theorem, as $\gcd(p,k) = 1, p \mid a$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $ak \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, for all $1 \leq k \leq p-1$. Then we've got $p-1$ distinct possible values of $k$. Since that, for every $k$ there must be a unique $r \in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ so that $ak \equiv r \pmod{p}$.

Comment: I still don't understand why r cannot appear twice for ak and ak'

Comment: Suppose $ak \equiv r \pmod{p}$ and $ak' \equiv r \pmod{p}$. Then $ak \equiv ak' \pmod{p}$. Using Euclid's Theorem again $$p \mid a(k-k') \Rightarrow p \mid k-k' \Rightarrow k \equiv k' \pmod{p}$$

But $k, k' \in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$, then $k = k'$.

Comment: @celes The fact that $r$ cannot appear twice is precisely what the word "distinct" means, hence why the author emphasizes the distinctness of the first $p-1$ multiples of $a$.  Both parts of your question have the same answer :).