# Proof of the theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have been unsuccessful in trying to find a proof of this theorem the name of which, if existing, I don't know.

> For any prime number $p$ and natural number $A$, where $p$ doesn't divide $A$, the remainder of $A^{p - 1}$ when divided by $p$ is $1$.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This is Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Note:  you need to add the assumption that $p\,\nmid\,A$ (the claim is clearly false if $p\,|\,A$).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730637/understanding-one-of-fermats-little-theorems-proof) is a link about proofs, but there are many more. Wikipedia gives several proofs, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure it would have helped you find it, but mathematicians writing in English about Fermat's "little" theorem generally prefer to use $a$ rather than $A$.

Also, you're missing the condition that $\gcd(a, p) = 1$. For example, if $a = 14$ and $p = 7$, we then have $14^6 = 7529536 \equiv 0$, not $1 \pmod 7$. If instead we try $a = 12$, which is coprime to $7$, we have $12^6 = 2985984 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, just like the theorem says.

So this would be a preferable way of stating the theorem:

> For any prime number $p$ and number $a$ coprime to $p$, the remainder of $a^{p - 1}$ when divided by $p$ is $1$.

One more thing: Fermat's "little" theorem is more generally useful than his "last" theorem, so some just say "Fermat's theorem" to refer to the "little" theorem.

Comment: Sometimes stated as : If  $p$ is prime then $p|(a^p-a)$ for all $a$....BTW. Fermat had a lot of other theorems, so it is better to say "little".